# Ajax appearing as undefined

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, undefined

So I'm currently working on this website app and I'm trying to show how many PC's are available in my University using the JSON from the University website and AJAX. I can't figure it out but its showing all the MACs for the first room and then its saying undefined for others, its all one block of code so I can't see where its going wrong any advice would be great.

JS:

```
    var container = $('div.container');
$('input#get').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '(mylink)',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        $.each(item, function(key, value) {
            container.append('<div class="pcsinside">' + value.displayName + '</div>' + 'PCs available:' + '&nbsp' + value.availPCs + '&nbsp' + 'out of' + '&nbsp' + value.numPCs + '<br/>' + 'Macs available:' + '&nbsp' + value.availMacs + '&nbsp' + 'out of' + '&nbsp' + value.numMacs + '<br/>');
           });

          });

         }
     });
})
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
            <div id="form-area">
            <input id="get" type="submit" value="Press For PC Availability">
            </div>
            <div class="pcsinside">
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is what it looks like and it does update whenever a PC changes for the PC's and the MACs except for the undefined ones.[image]

It works for the first one but not for the other MACs, whats going on? Any help would be really appreciated thanks guys.

Comment: value.availMacs is not correct, check you json response

Comment: check data and item using console.log first , also provide data json here

Answer (score 0):

First in dataType you put 'jsonp' instead of 'json'. And S Jayesh is right, you must stringify to see the answer. See this exemple.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "blabla.php",
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(data){
        var err = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(err);
    },
    success: function(data){
        var succ = JSON.stringify(data);
alert(succ);
    }
});
```

With that structure, you'll see what is the problem. Use post instead of get, it's better.

Comment: I cant use json, I need jsonp or it will get blocked by the CORS policy.

Comment: I'm not sure, on jsonp, can you stringify ? Test it. if you can, use same way to test the problem. Cause for now, you must target your problem. Worst thing, is trying alot of things. Remove everything in success, just test your answer with a alert like "success" if stringify not working. Add error part and put alert "error". Replace the part of php like i told you ans test your answer, just that. With that way you'll be sure. After try another test. Other possibility, try with pure json on a localhost and after convert to jsonp. As i read, jsonp is pretty similar, unlike padding. Good luck

Answer (score -2):

To display JSON as string you need to use `JSON.stringify()` function :

```
container.append('<div>'+ JSON.stringify(value.displayName) +'</div>');
```

Comment: I tried it out and it didn't work, but I appreciate the feedback. :)

Comment: In success function:   `var results = JSON.parse(data);      var lengthOfData = results.length; `   then you can iterate using simple **for** loop (say, i as iterator) and then get the value as  `var displayNmae = JSON.stringify(results[i]["displayNameKey"]);`    Here I am considering your `data` is a JSON array.