# Read json line by line odoo and ajax

Tags: json, ajax, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

My controller return:

```
@http.route('/my_json', type="json", auth="public")
    def some_json(self):
         return json.dumps({"ids":[{"id": 1,"name": "Audi"},{"id": 2,"name": "BMW"},{"id": 3,"name": "OPEL"}]})
```

How in new html page in div load data eg.

1   Audi

2   BMW

3   Opel

function callJson() {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/test_json", 
    async: false, 
    data: JSON.stringify({}), 
    contentType: "application/json", 
    complete: function (data) { 
            alert(data["responseText"])
    },
    error: function () {
          alert("Error")
          }
     });
```

alert return:

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "result": "{\"ids\": [{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"Audi\"}, {\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"BMW\"}, {\"id\": 3, \"name\": \"Opel\"}]}"}

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer along with comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43774063/7081346) and you can use

`JSON.stringify(results['ids'][i]['id'])`.

Answer (score 0):

In you case, you don't need using the json.dumps.

In odoo you have 2 possibilities for the type of route.

1. HTML.

The method must return a string or a rendering method

```
@http.route('/my_html_render', type="html", auth="public")
def html_render(self):
    value_dict = {'a':'hello'}
    return request.render('template_name',value_dict )

@http.route('/my_html_string', type="html", auth="public")
def html_string(self):
    return "Hello world"
```

2. JSON

Odoo will convert in json format your dictionary.

```
@http.route('/my_json', type="json", auth="public")
def some_json(self):
    return {"ids":[{"id": 1,"name": "Audi"},{"id": 2,"name": "BMW"},{"id": 3,"name": "OPEL"}]}
```